# Code::Blocks linux glext.h "reference to uint64_t is ambiguous"

Tags: c++, linux, opengl, codeblocks, glfw

I am making an OpenGL application using Code::Blocks in Xubuntu 14.04 with GLFW3 installed from source. In eclipse CDT it works but in this IDE an error message shows up when compiling:

```
[...]
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1404|error: reference to ‘uint64_t’ is ambiguous|
/usr/include/stdint.h|55|note: candidates are: typedef long unsigned int uint64_t|
third_party/glm/fwd.hpp|907|note:                 typedef glm::detail::uint64                 glm::uint64_t|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1404|error: ‘uint64_t’ does not name a type|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1405|error: reference to ‘int64_t’ is ambiguous|
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/types.h|197|note: candidates are: typedef long int int64_t|
third_party/glm/fwd.hpp|305|note:                 typedef glm::detail::int64 glm::int64_t|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1405|error: ‘int64_t’ does not name a type|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1478|error: ‘GLuint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1479|error: ‘GLuint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1480|error: ‘GLint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1482|error: ‘GLint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1483|error: ‘GLint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1547|error: ‘GLint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|1548|error: ‘GLuint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2447|error: ‘GLint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2591|error: reference to ‘uint64_t’ is ambiguous|
/usr/include/stdint.h|55|note: candidates are: typedef long unsigned int uint64_t|
third_party/glm/fwd.hpp|907|note:                 typedef glm::detail::uint64 glm::uint64_t|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2591|error: ‘uint64_t’ does not name a type|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2593|error: typedef ‘GLuint64’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2593|error: ‘PFNGLGETTEXTUREHANDLEARBPROC’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2594|error: typedef ‘GLuint64’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2594|error: ‘PFNGLGETTEXTURESAMPLERHANDLEARBPROC’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2595|error: typedef ‘PFNGLMAKETEXTUREHANDLERESIDENTARBPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2595|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2596|error: typedef ‘PFNGLMAKETEXTUREHANDLENONRESIDENTARBPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2596|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2597|error: typedef ‘GLuint64’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2597|error: ‘PFNGLGETIMAGEHANDLEARBPROC’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2598|error: typedef ‘PFNGLMAKEIMAGEHANDLERESIDENTARBPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2598|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2598|error: expected primary-expression before ‘access’|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2599|error: typedef ‘PFNGLMAKEIMAGEHANDLENONRESIDENTARBPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2599|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2600|error: ‘GLuint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2601|error: ‘GLuint64’ does not name a type|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2602|error: ‘GLuint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2603|error: ‘GLuint64’ does not name a type|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2604|error: typedef ‘PFNGLISTEXTUREHANDLERESIDENTARBPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2604|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2605|error: typedef ‘PFNGLISIMAGEHANDLERESIDENTARBPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2605|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2606|error: ‘GLuint64EXT’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2607|error: ‘GLuint64EXT’ does not name a type|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|2608|error: ‘GLuint64EXT’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|7547|error: ‘GLint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|7548|error: ‘GLuint64’ has not been declared|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8235|error: typedef ‘GLuint64’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8235|error: ‘PFNGLGETTEXTUREHANDLENVPROC’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8236|error: typedef ‘GLuint64’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8236|error: ‘PFNGLGETTEXTURESAMPLERHANDLENVPROC’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8237|error: typedef ‘PFNGLMAKETEXTUREHANDLERESIDENTNVPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8237|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8238|error: typedef ‘PFNGLMAKETEXTUREHANDLENONRESIDENTNVPROC’ is initialized (use decltype instead)|
/usr/include/GL/glext.h|8238|error: ‘GLuint64’ was not declared in this scope|
||More errors follow but not being shown.|
||Edit the max errors limit in compiler options...|
||=== Build failed: 50 error(s), 1 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

The compiler is GNU GCC and the code is c++11. The linked libraries are in this order:

```
X11
pthread
Xrandr
Xi
Xxf86vm
rt
m
GL
```

Linker search directories:

```
/usr/lib
/usr/local/lib
/usr/include           *Tried in Compiler search directories too
/usr/local/include     *Tried in Compiler search directories too
```

If you need anything more, just ask.
PD: I'm not including the GL headers directly, glfw3 does it for me.

Comment: This problem doesn't relates to linking. I'd better you shown us your source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems, that in your code (or code of GLFW3) you have something like:

```
using namespace glm::detail;
```

That brings other definition of `uint64_t` in your namespace. If you want to specify what type you want to use, you may either remove `using namespace` or fully specify type you want to use; it would be either `::uint64_t` or `glm::detail::uint64_t`.

As another solution try changing order of your include files.